# I want to change value of data if countdown timer has passed in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I'm making a Queueing system and I want the called queue number to go back to last queue in case the user doesn't show for the transaction for a given period of time. Please help me how to do this.

This is my function for calling a queue:

```
public function callqueue(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'called'  => ['max:255'],
        'counter' => ['max:255']
    ]);

    $dept = Auth::user()->department;
    $call = Queue::where([
            ['department',$dept],
            ['called', 'no']
        ])
        ->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->first();

    if ( ! is_null($call)) {
        $call->update([
            'called'  => $request->called,
            'counter' => $request->counter
        ]);
        $call->save();
        event(new NewQueue($call));
        return redirect('admin')->withStatus(__('Queue has been called.'));
    } else {
        return redirect('admin')->withStatus(__('No available queue for calling.'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions: 1) what other methods will your queue system have? 2) is 'callqueue' effectively popping an item off the queue? If so, why are we searching with 'created_at' set to 'today'? 3) why create a new queue item when we update the old queue item? does the ::where() method remove the item from the queue? It's hard to answer without understanding more

Comment: callqueue function is just updating the queue data value. What I wanted to happen is when a queue is called, it will go back to the last queue if the client is NO-SHOW or not reponding within 5 minutes.

Comment: What doesn't work in your code? What is it supposed to do that it isn't doing?

Comment: my code just plain calling a queue for the queuing system. I want a feature that when a queue is called,it will go back to the last line of queue if the person doesnt show for 5mins.

Comment: I think you need to update the question to provide a lot more information, include inputs and outputs, and probably more code. It sounds like you need to implement the concept of transactionality but I'm not even certain. Would library implemented transactionality be suitable? Please expand your question, I think it's unanswerable at the moment. You should be able to point at a specific issue with your attempt and ask 'why isn't this working?' or 'I'm seeing "x" but I would have expected "y"? At the moment it isn't clear there has been an attempt made. Sorry but that's just my honest view

Comment: @sigel did you find any solution? What about my answer I have posted below?

Answer (score 0):

I have created similar queue system, do comment if you need any modification

> I want the called queue number to go back to last queue in case the
> user doesn't show for the transaction for a given period of time.

On queue table put 2 timestamps `last_updated_at` and `next_update_at`

Pick the first in queue ordering by `nexy_update_at`

```
$call=Queue::...
    ->where('next_update_at', '>', Carbon::now()->timestamp) # I recommend to use timestamp not datetime
    ->orderBy('next_update_at', 'asc')
    ->first();

if ($call) {
// do the task
}
```

Now whenever person shows up in website or anything you wish, just pick his queue task and  update the `next_update_at`

```
Queue::where('user_id', ...)
    ->...
    ->update(['next_update_at', now()->timestamp]);
```